# LINQ / LAMBDA expression for the below code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a checked list box from which i extracted the checked items value and saved it to database. Now when i am returning back to form i am having only the value [id] as a List. Now i want to display those selected values from this list of int.

I think i am clear to you.

**[Update]**

Hi, I solved my issue , using the below code. But i want to know is there any more optimized solution than this one. As its iterating unneccesarily

```
private void ProcessRequest()
        {
            if (Session["DeniedReason"] != null)
            {
                List<int> deniedList = (List<int>)Session["DeniedReason"];
                if(deniedList!=null)
                {
                    if(deniedList.Count>0)
                    {
                        foreach (int deniedValue in deniedList)
                        {
                            foreach (ListItem item in cblDeniedList.Items)
                            {
                                if (string.Compare(item.Value,deniedValue.ToString())==0)
                                {
                                    item.Selected = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

LINQ / Lambda expression if any..that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<int> deniedList = (List<int>)Session["DeniedReason"];
foreach (ListItem li in cblDeniedList.Items)
{
    li.Selected = deniedList.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(li.Value));
}
```

Comment: Weird... I posted this answer to a different question. Something weird going on behind the scenes.

Comment: no thanks , its the same question... i have edited the question

Comment: List<int> selected = new List<int>(); //populate from database
foreach (ListItem li in chkDisplayList.Items)
{
        li.Selected = selected.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(li.Value));
}

Comment: Thanks Karel, updated the answer with the simplified expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:checkboxlist id="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" 
      DataTextField="interest" DataValueField="1" />
Use DatavalueFild property(i think it's your id)
ListItem myListItem = CheckBoxList1.Items.FindByValue("sports"); 
 currentCheckBox.Selected = true;
```

or use CheckBoxList1.Items.FindByText method
Hope this helps:-)
It's answer for you nonupdated question